# Imread returns 4 dimensions when 3 expected. Why?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am working on a convolutional neural network based in tensorflow. To handle the transformations, SciKit functions reshape the original images. I have an unexpected situation where:

```
def read_img(file):
   img = skimage.io.imread(img_folder + file)
   print(img.shape)
   img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (img_width, img_height), mode=mode)
   return img[:,:,:img_channels]
```

stops the model from forming as the following traceback:

```
File "A:\anoth\...\newmodel.py", line 76, in read_img
img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (img_width, img_height), mode=mode)
File "A:\anoth\...\\skimage\transform\_warps.py", line 124, in resize
raise ValueError("len(output_shape) cannot be smaller than the image "
ValueError: len(output_shape) cannot be smaller than the image dimensions
```

The print of the input variable (`print(img.shape)`) demonstrates that there is an image entering the model that consists of 4 dimensions

```
(2, 480, 720, 3)
```

when the previous files have 3 like:

```
(480, 720, 3)
```

What might be happening here? What is this 4th dimension when the inputs are all images?

Comment: Consider printing the name of the *"unhappy"* image and checking it with external utilities.

Comment: It's a gif. The 2 is the layering. It was not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is that of an animated GIF.